# Unable to install IIS 7 on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

We are unable to install IIS 7 on windows server 2008 R2. After analyzing few things, the Server Manager was also not working and was prompting for continues reboot. Now, somehow we fixed the Server Manager issue by referring to the below link:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1b4c68d4-22f6-4dcd-820d-037c665bf2f9/missing-window-server-2008-files-where-do-i-find-these-files-they-are-not-on-the-installation?forum=winservermanager

But unable to fix IIS 7 installation issue. Could someone please help me to resolve the issue?

Screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Check Event Viewer for errors at the time of failure. You will need more information to find the root cause.

Comment: Thanks!. I involved Microsoft in this case. It found to be an issue with Windows Process Activation Service and IIS, were not uninstalled properly. MS have performed backend operations to clear all footprints of WAS and IIS and reinstalled. That resolved the issue.